# If GNU screen already exists, reattach to it, else create it

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I'm trying to do this: if a GNU screen named `worker` already exists, then reattach to it, else create it by starting `python example.py`.

I tried:

```
if [ls /var/run/screen/S-root/ |grep -Fxq worker] then screen -r worker else cd /home/www/example/; screen -S worker python example.py fi
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there something wrong in the syntax?

Comment: What do you mean by this screen -S worker python example.py, you want to create a session and run python example.py in it ?

Comment: @Bharat yes, if the session is not already running and detached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes more sense to use `screen -ls` or

```
screen -S worker -x || { cd /home/www/example; screen -S worker python example.py; }
```

But the errors in your code are

1. the unnecessary `[` (which would have needed spaces around it)

   ```
   if [ls /var/run/screen/S-root/ |grep -Fxq worker]
   ```

   must be

   ```
   if ls /var/run/screen/S-root/ | grep -Fxq worker
   ```
2. the missing `;` / newline before `then`

   ```
   |grep -Fxq worker] then
   ```

   must be

   ```
   | grep -Fxq worker; then
   ```
3. the missing `;` / newline before `else`

   ```
    then screen -r worker else
   ```

   must be

   ```
    then screen -r worker; else
   ```
4. the missing `;` / newline before `fi`

   ```
   python example.py fi
   ```

   must be

   ```
   python example.py; fi
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution `screen -S worker -x || { ... }` works fine. And I learnt about the missing `;` + unncessary `[`, thanks as well!

Comment: @Basj I use that every day because I start `screen` as root with the config file of my normal user account.

Comment: Also my `-Fxq` was wrong. `if screen -ls |grep -Fq worker; then screen -r worker; else cd /home/www/example/; screen -S worker python example.py; fi` is correct.